# reload route not showing component

Tags: angular, routes

I have a project with a routing module with the following paths:

```
{ path: 'account-settings', component: AccountSettingsComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'account', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'password', component: PasswordComponent,  data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent,  data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'preferences', component: PreferencesComponent,  data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'security', component: SecurityComponent,  data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
    ]
  }
```

this project is imported in another bigger project like this

```
  {
    path: 'learning',
    loadChildren: './../../projects/pxLearning/src/app/app.module#LearningModule',
  },
```

when I try to access this route (by clicking on a button with  `[routerLink]="['/learning/account-settings/account']"`)

```
/learning/account-settings/account
```

the AccountComponent(or the others) is working fine

BUT if I am trying to refresh the page, the same route won't instantiate the AccountComponent(or the others). The same thing happens it I type the url in browser, won't instantiate the components.

Why is this happening?

edit:
LearningGuard

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (state.url.indexOf('learning') === -1) {
      this.router.navigate(['/learning/' + state.url]);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: you should set up your backend server configuration to serve it as an SPA, which usually means to redirect all non source requests to `index.html`

Comment: It might be an issue with the LearningRedirectGuard. Can you show the guard please?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, I just edited the post with the code

Answer (score 0):

```
if (state.url.indexOf('learning') === -1) {
```

You could rewrite this line to

```
if (!state.url.contain('learning')) {
```

So you always navigate, when you are NOT on a learning route right now. This means you are redirected to another route, which likely doesn't even exist and your routes doesn't match any component.